# Глюки и галлюцианции

Tags: жаргон, этимология

Жаргонное слово "глюк" уже прочно вошло в нашу речь, особенно, в речь тех, кто работает с компьютером, потому что употребляется оно чаще не в значении галлюцинаций у наркоманов, а как обозначение сбоев в работе компьютера. 
А откуда, собственно, вообще взялось слово? Я всегда считала, что произошло все-таки от "галлюцинаций": галлюцинации-галлюники-глюки, и происходит из наркоманского жаргона. Но при чем тут тогда компьютер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Компьютер - тоже "мозг", который даёт сбои и у которого могут быть "заскоки" (глюки). Происхождение слова - для меня загадка, но что касается "мозговитости" компьютера, в китайском это слово (дянь нао) составлено из двух  иероглифов, буквально означающих "электрический мозг".

P.S. Что касается употребления слова по отношению к людям за пределами сообщества наркозависимых. Я *никогда* не слышал, чтобы его осознанно связывали с *галлюцинациями*. Это обычно была аналогия с более часто упоминаемыми компьютерными "глюками": случаи эксцентричного поведения, "заскоки", странные ошибки (иногда иронично о себе). Скорее, это ближе к намеку на лёгкие проблемы с психикой у кого-то, а не конкретно о "видениях".

Comment: И я о том же! С галлюцинациями это слово связывают очень редко!

Answer (score 2):

Кроме глюков, есть еще галюны и глюники (жарг.) с тем же значением.

Таким образом, длинное медицинское слово "галлюцинации" (19 век, неологизм фр. психиатра Эскиролю от лат. hallutinare - сходить с ума)постепенно трансформировалось в глюки.